# Can I limit OpenGL version to 4.3?

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I have an OpenGL 4.5 capable GPU and I wish to test if my application runs on an OpenGL 4.3 capable system. Can I set my GPU to use OpenGL 4.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you forcibly limit your OpenGL implementation to a specific version? No. Implementations are permitted to give you any version which is 100% compatible with the one you asked for. And 4.5 is compatible with 4.3.

However, using the right [OpenGL loading library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library), you can forcibly limit your *header*. Several libraries allow you to generate version-specific headers, which will provide APIs and enums for *just* that version and nothing else. And any extensions you wish to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you validate this with an example? I'm currently using GLEW in my project but can change that if necessary.

Comment: @Andreas here's an example of generating headers and loader using [glad](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad): `glad --out-path=./glad --generator=c --api="gl=4.3" --extensions=""`. Just don't forget to include the generated `glad.c` to source files list (and `-ldl` to linker flags if you're on Linux). For another generators see the link in this answer.